# Is there a difference between '' and "" in TypeScript syntax?

Tags: angular, typescript, syntax

I am using TypeScript for Angular and I've noted that there are some places where we only use **' '** and in others  only **" "**.
What's the difference?

Answer (score 0):

These are js string literals. the only difference is that inside " " string single' are auto-escaped and vise versa, inside of ' ' string double" are auto-escaped.

Usually single quotes are preferred in js, and even there is a popular eslint rule that enforces single quotes usage

Comment: They aren't "autoescaped". They *do not need escaping*. The string `"a"` doesn't "autoescape" the character `a`. Same with the string `"'"` - the character `'` is just a normal character.

Comment: "*usually single quotes are more preffered in js, and even there is a popular eslint rule that enforces single quotes usage*" the [popular ESLint rule](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/quotes) enforces one style of quotes. Of your choice. Not "single quotes". Also, the default config value is `"double"`.

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference except that `"` can be used without escaping it in a string defined with `'` and the same for `'` in a string defined with `"`.

Both define a Typescript `string`.